# Map function to apply to each item of tuple

Tags: functions, notation

Is there a mathematical function or notation for applying a function to each item of a tuple which returns a new tuple with items that correspond with the 'mapped' items of the original?

e.g. if $f(x) = x^2$ and $T = (1, 2, 3)$, it could be something like $map(T, f)$ which would return $(1, 4, 9)$.

Comment: Often times, people might just write $f(T)$, which is an abuse of notation. This is fine, but you should probably make a note of it in whatever you are writing if you plan on using this convention.

Comment: This is one of a handful of questions you've recently asked about doing programming-like calculations in mathematical notation (and one of three with tuples specifically). These sorts of manipulations are not often done in mathematical notation, so while they can be done, they usually wouldn't be. I wonder if there is an underlying question like "can the core idea of this algorithm be rephrased without tuples, or how might a mathematician think about this algorithm written in this functional language?" that would clear up the need for these individual questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your notation suggests, things like this are done in programming, often with a name like map. See [the English Wikipedia page for the higher-order function "map"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) for discussion and notation. But in mathematical notation, this would not usually be thought of in quite this way. Depending on the emphasis/application, there are a few ways things might be phrased.

If the length of the input tuple is fixed and small, then we can use a [(cartesian) product of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_product_of_functions): $f\times f\times f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ would send $(1,2,3)$ to $(1,4,9)$. If it's fixed and large, I could imagine someone writing $f^{17}$ to denote $\underbrace{f\times f\times\cdots\times f}_{17\text{ }f\text{s}}$, but that would be so unusual it would need to be explained.

If the length of the tuple is not fixed (or infinite), then it would be common to use an ad-hoc notation for the sequences under consideration. Perhaps something like:

> Let $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ be the finite sequence of [whatever]s. Then define $b_i=f(a_i)$ for each $i$, so that $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ has [whatever desired property].

If it's really necessary to be completely modular, then you'd have to define something brand new. Perhaps something like:

> Taking inspiration from functional programming languages, if $\mathbf a$ is a finite sequence of reals $a_i$, and $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, we define $f_{>}(\mathbf a)$ [or $\mathrm{map}(f,\mathbf a)$, etc.] to be the sequence of corresponding $f(a_i)$.